# How to install Wagtail 5.1 or above

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am using MacOS.  I tried to install **Wagtail 5.1** in a venv and I installed `pip install wagtail`. and `wagtail start mysite mysite`.  Without using cd mysite
`pip install -r requirements.txt`, I directly typed cd mysite and `python manage.py migrate`.  That because I needed to install Wagtail 5.1 and not Wagtail 2.1. But when I tried to python manage.py migrate, It shows many errors including ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘wagtail.core’.  How could I install Wagtail 5.1 or above as a fresh install?

This is what I got

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/catman/Documents/dev/wt/mydir/catproject/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/catman/Documents/dev/wt/mydir/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/catman/Documents/dev/wt/mydir/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/catman/Documents/dev/wt/mydir/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/catman/Documents/dev/wt/mydir/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/catman/Documents/dev/wt/mydir/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail.core'
```

Comment: Have you activated a virtual environment (venv) to install the dependencies?